# Requesting a PayPal preapproval screen suitable for a responsive web application

Tags: web-applications, paypal, responsive-design, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Currently I am able to generate and authorize a preapproval key using PayPal's adaptive payments API.
Therefore I am requesting an authorization form via the following url:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=PA-xxxxxxxxxxxx

This works, but it is loading a full screen website.

In order to implement PayPal's preapproval in a responsive web application I am looking for the correct url to request the minibrowser solution.
In the [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) the following url to request the preapproval authorization screen can be found:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/preapproval?preapprovalKey=PA-xxxxxxxxxxxx&expType=mini

Because I am still in sandbox mode, I have added sandbox to the url:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/preapproval?preapprovalKey=PA-xxxxxxxxxxxx&expType=mini

This url does not work and leads to the message from the image below.

What is the correct url for getting a mini version of the preapproval authorization screen (in sandbox mode)?
Or, are other solutions known for making the preapproval authorization screen responsive?

[image: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/preapproval?preapprovalKey=PA-xxxxxxxxxxxx&expType=mini]

Comment: I am having same problem. If you have found solution, will you please share it with me or here as answer of this question ? It will be much appreciated.